# uploading app to apple app store

Tags: iphone, app-store

I want to submit my app to appstore. But I have a credit card of Indian Bank. Does that mean I can upload my app only for Indian app store. Or it doesn't matter?

Comment: Is you app free?  If so, then it doesn't matter.

Comment: I think you should ask this in apple.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @entropy I think the jury's still out on that :  http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1038/what-would-happen-if-we-expanded-the-scope-of-this-site-to-include-itunes-connec still off topic here though.

Answer (score 2):

Once you're set up as an Apple iOS developer, you should be able to sell your apps in any country's app store.

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter what credit card you own.

Answer (score -1):

I would think it should matter. After all, my US bank card based app gets uploaded to other stores. I have downloads all over the world. But, if you can, just call Apple Developer at (800) 633-2152 and ask them.